# Placing a Tikzpicture and Matrix together

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I need help a little on the matrix again and putting together the matrix and tikzpicture I created.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} %%% For curly braces
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,matrix,positioning}


\begin{document}

The Tikzpicture

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,0)--(9,0);
\draw (3,2pt)--(3,-2pt) node[below] {\textcolor{red}{$-3$}};
\draw (6,2pt)--(6,-2pt) node[below] {\textcolor{red}{$3$}};
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=5pt},decorate]
 (0,0) -- node[above=6pt,align=center] {$(-\infty,3)$} (2.95,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=5pt},decorate]
 (3.05,0) -- node[above=6pt,align=center] {$(-3,3)$} (5.95,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=5pt},decorate]
 (6.05,0) -- node[above=6pt,align=center] {$(3,\infty)$} (9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

The Matrix

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[wide/.style={text width=#1,fill=green!40!gray}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={align=center,inner sep=3pt,anchor=center,
ultra thin,draw},draw,inner 
sep=0pt,ampersand replacement=\&] (mat1)
at (0,0){
f^{\prime}(-4)>0 \& f^{\prime}(0)<0 \& f^{\prime}(4)>0  \\
 |[text width=33mm,wide=33mm]| {\text{Test Value}} \& 
|[text width=33mm,minimum height=.5cm]| {$x=-4 $} \&
 |[text width=33mm,minimum height=.5cm]| {$x=0$} \&
|[text width=33mm,minimum height=.5cm]| {$x=4$} \&    \\
 |[text width=33mm,wide=33mm]| \text{Sign of $f^{\prime}(x)$} \& 
|[text width=33mm,minimum height=.5cm]| {$f^{\prime}(-4)>0$} \&
 |[text width=33mm,minimum height=.5cm]| {$f^{\prime}(0)<0$} \&
|[text width=33mm,minimum height=.5cm]| {$f^{\prime}(4)>0$} \&    \\
|[wide=33mm]| {\strut Result\\} \& 
|[text width=33mm]| {\strut $f$ is increasing \\ on $(-\infty,-3)$} \& 
|[text width=33mm]| {\strut $f$ is decreasing \\ on $(-3,3)$} \&
|[text width=33mm]| {\strut $f$ is decreasing \\ on $(3,\infty)$}  \& \\                       
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This Outputs:

[image]

I am trying to put them together like in this (but a different yet similar example):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

i merge both `tikzpicture`s in one. arrow and braces positions are determined relatively to matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathreplacing,  % For curly braces
                matrix,
                positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
B/.style = {decoration={brace,raise=2mm,amplitude=1mm,
                        pre=moveto,pre length=1pt,
                        post=moveto,post length=1pt},thick, decorate},
arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, red, thick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
box/.style = {fill=white, text width=24mm, align=center, inner sep=0.5mm,
              font=\footnotesize, pos=0.25, 
              anchor=center,yshift=-2ex}
                    ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes={thin, draw,
                    text width=28mm, minimum height=4ex, align=center,
                    inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
             column 1/.style = {nodes={text width=21mm,
                                align=left,fill=olive!50}},
                row 3/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8ex}},
             ]
{
\text{Test Value}
    &  x=-4                &  x=0             &  x=4             \\
\text{Sign of } f^{\prime}(x)
    &  f^{\prime}(-4)>0    &  f^{\prime}(0)<0 &  f^{\prime}(4)>0 \\
\text{Result}
    &  \begin{gathered} f \text{ is increasing on}\\
        (-\infty,-3)
        \end{gathered}
        &  \begin{gathered} f \text{ is decreasing on}\\
        (-3,3)
        \end{gathered}
        &  \begin{gathered} f \text{ is decreasing on}\\
        (3,\infty)
        \end{gathered}          \\
};
\coordinate[above=7mm of m-1-1.north]   (aux1);
\coordinate[above=1mm of aux1]          (aux2);
\draw[Stealth-Stealth,thick] (aux1)  -- (aux1 -| m-1-4.east);
\draw (aux2 -| m-1-3.west) -- + (0,-2mm) node[below] {\textcolor{red}{$-3$}}
      (aux2 -| m-1-3.east) -- + (0,-2mm) node[below] {\textcolor{red}{$3$}};
\draw[B]    (aux1) --
    node[above=3mm] {$(-\infty,-3)$}
            (aux1 -| m-1-2.east);
\draw[B]    (aux1 -| m-1-3.west) --
    node[above=3mm] {$(-3,3)$}
            (aux1 -| m-1-3.east);
\draw[B]    (aux1 -| m-1-4.west) --
    node[above=3mm] {$(3,\infty)$}
            (aux1 -| m-1-4.east);
\draw[arr]
    (m-3-2.south) -- + (0,-0.6) -| ([xshift=-2mm] m-3-3.south)
    node[box] {Change indicates relative maximum at $x=-3$};
\draw[arr]
    ([xshift=2mm] m-3-3.south) -- + (0,-0.6) -| (m-3-4.south)
    node[box] {Change indicates relative minimum at $x=3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** added are red arrows with text (below of the matrix) and defined minimum height for cells in the last matrix's row.

Comment: this is fantastic! Yes if you could add the text below, that would be great!

Comment: @MathScholar, done. also added missed end part of the mwe (happen at copy-past procedure ...)

Comment: @Zarko, I feel my minimal example had nothing to do with the final solution. Thank you very much for this. Studying the manual must have taken you to this level of programming. I would not have been able to write on my own at this time!